# C# вопрос по ООП

Tags: c#, ооп

Задумался как сделать логичнее (правильнее). Есть два класса: один ставит лайки в нём два метода лайки по тэгу и лайки по геолокации, второй подписывается в нём тоже два метода подписываться по тэгу и по геолокации.

Получается так, что у меня практически полностью дублируется один и тот же код в этих методах и классах. Разница в коде буквально в паре полей. Т.е. очень не удобно   когда что-то меняешь, приходится менять всё тоже самое ещё в 3х методах.

Понимаю, что можно было бы сделать один класс с одним методом например: *_work.Run(param1,param2,param3 ...);* , но думаю это потом негативно отразится при глобальном расширении проекта. А я хочу сделать два класса, что логичнее на мой взгляд и потом проще для понимания. *_like.Run(param1,param2,param3 ...)* и *_subscribe.Run(param1,param2,param3 ...)* но при этом что бы код методов не дублировался в каждом классе.

UPD

Запуск из формы

```
 try
        {

            //обратите внимание на передачу токена отмены, и экземпл. прогресса


            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  //new thread

                if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
                    {
                        _like.Tags(tag, time_wait, limit, filters, cancelToken);
                    }
                    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
                    {
                        _like.Geolocation(geonumber, time_wait, limit, filters, cancelToken);
                    }
                }
                if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //подписка по тэгу
                        _subscribe.Tags(tag, time_wait, limit, filters, cancelToken);
                    }
                    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
                    {
                        _subscribe.Geolocation(geonumber, time_wait, limit, filters, cancelToken);
                    }
                }

            });


        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Задача отменена.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("В задаче произошла ошибка: " + ex, "Threads error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
```

класс Subscribe

```
 class Subscribe
{
    String filter_view_in_msg_box = "без фильтров";
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    private ControlFormProgramm _controlFormProgramm;

    public Subscribe(IWebDriver driver, ControlFormProgramm controlFormProgramm)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        _controlFormProgramm = controlFormProgramm;
    }
    public void Tags(string tag, int time_wait, int limit, string filters, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + tag);
        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).Click(); // открыть пост Самая первая запись в теге
        double dlimit = Convert.ToDouble(limit);


        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {

            if (Form1.stoped != 1)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (GetIsCheckedSubscribe() == false && Filters_word(filters) == true)
                    {
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);



                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button")).Click(); //кнопка подпис. в открытом посте
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " подписались" + " (" + filter_view_in_msg_box + ")");
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100));
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");

                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_wait));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " пропускаем, уже подписаны или фильтр");
                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        i = i - 1;
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");
                    }

                    if (i >= limit)
                    { //цикл выполнен
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Завершено.");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Завершено.");
                        _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("Error: " + e.Message);
                    i = i - 1;
                    _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост
                }
            }                //принудительная остановка
            else
            {
                i = limit;
                _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Остановлено.");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Остановлено.");
                _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
            }

        }



    }

    public void Geolocation(string geonumber, int time_wait, int limit, string filters, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/" + geonumber);
        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).Click(); // открыть пост Самая первая запись в теге
        double dlimit = Convert.ToDouble(limit);


        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {

            if (Form1.stoped != 1)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (GetIsCheckedSubscribe() == false && Filters_word(filters) == true)
                    {
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);



                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button")).Click(); //кнопка подпис. в открытом посте
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " подписались" + " (" + filter_view_in_msg_box + ")");
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100));
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");

                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_wait));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " пропускаем, уже подписаны или фильтр");
                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        i = i - 1;
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");
                    }

                    if (i >= limit)
                    { //цикл выполнен
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Завершено.");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Завершено.");
                        _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("Error: " + e.Message);
                    i = i - 1;
                    _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост
                }
            }                //принудительная остановка
            else
            {
                i = limit;
                _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Остановлено.");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Остановлено.");
                _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
            }

        }



    }

    public Boolean GetIsCheckedSubscribe()
    {
        String getAttribut;
        Boolean ischeck;

        getAttribut = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button")).GetAttribute("class");
       Console.WriteLine(getAttribut); 

       if (getAttribut == "oW_lN _0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d    _8A5w5    ")
        {
            ischeck = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ischeck = false;
        }

        return ischeck;

    }

    public Boolean Filters_word(string _filter_words)
    {
        bool result;
        String bodyText=" ";
        if (Form1.MyGlavForm.checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            String filters = _filter_words;
            try
            {
                IWebElement body = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > div.EtaWk"));
                bodyText = body.Text; //текст поста #react-root > section > main > div > div > article > div.eo2As > div.KlCQn.EtaWk > ul > li > div > div > div > span
            }
            catch (Exception ) { filter_view_in_msg_box = "null"; return result = true; }

                                         // Console.WriteLine(bodyText);

            string[] words = filters.Split(',');

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                result = Regex.IsMatch(bodyText, @"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (result == true)
                {
                    filter_view_in_msg_box = word;
                    return result;

                }

            }
            return result = false;
        }
        else { return result = true; }

    }
}
```

Класс лайкер

```
 class Like
{
    String filter_view_in_msg_box = "без фильтров";
    private IWebDriver _driver;
            private ControlFormProgramm _controlFormProgramm;

    public Like(IWebDriver driver, ControlFormProgramm controlFormProgramm) {
        _driver = driver;
        _controlFormProgramm = controlFormProgramm;
    }



    public void Tags(string tag, int time_wait, int limit, string filters, CancellationToken cancelToken) {

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+tag);
        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).Click(); // открыть пост Самая первая запись в теге
        double dlimit = Convert.ToDouble(limit);



        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {

            if (Form1.stoped != 1)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (GetIsCheckedLike() == false && Filters_word(filters)==true)
                    {
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);



                         _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button")).Click(); //кнопка лайка в открытом посте
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " лайк добавлен" +" ("+filter_view_in_msg_box+")");
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100));
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");

                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_wait));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " пропускаем, уже лайкали или фильтр");
                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        i = i - 1;
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");
                    }

                    if (i >= limit)
                    { //цикл выполнен
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Завершено.");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Завершено.");
                        _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("Error: " + e.Message);
                    i = i - 1;
                    _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост
                }
            }                //принудительная остановка
            else {
                i = limit;
                _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Остановлено.");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Остановлено.");
                _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
            }

        }



    }

    public void Geolocation(string geonumber, int time_wait, int limit, string filters, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {

        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/" + geonumber);
        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")).Click(); // открыть пост Самая первая запись в теге
        double dlimit = Convert.ToDouble(limit);



        for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
        {

            if (Form1.stoped != 1)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (GetIsCheckedLike() == false && Filters_word(filters) == true)
                    {
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);



                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button")).Click(); //кнопка лайка в открытом посте
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " лайк добавлен" + " (" + filter_view_in_msg_box + ")");
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100));
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");

                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time_wait));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cancelToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg(_driver.Url + " пропускаем, уже лайкали или фильтр");
                        _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост

                        i = i - 1;
                        double di = Convert.ToDouble(i);
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel(limit + " / " + i + " (" + Convert.ToInt32(di / dlimit * 100) + " %)");
                    }

                    if (i >= limit)
                    { //цикл выполнен
                        _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Завершено.");
                        ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                        _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Завершено.");
                        _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("Error: " + e.Message);
                    i = i - 1;
                    _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")).Click(); //следующий пост
                }
            }                //принудительная остановка
            else
            {
                i = limit;
                _controlFormProgramm.ProcessBarSetValue(100);
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("      Остановлено.");
                ControlFormProgramm.MsgLogBox.AddMsg("=======================");
                _controlFormProgramm.SetTextStateLabel("Остановлено.");
                _controlFormProgramm.Stop();
            }

        }



    }

    public Boolean GetIsCheckedLike()
    {
        String getAttribut;
        Boolean ischeck;
        getAttribut = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button > span")).GetAttribute("class");
        Console.WriteLine(getAttribut); 
        if (getAttribut == "glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7")
        {
            ischeck = false;
        }
        else {
            ischeck = true;
        }

        return ischeck;

    }

    public Boolean Filters_word(string _filter_words)
    {
        bool result;
        String bodyText = " ";
        if (Form1.MyGlavForm.checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            String filters = _filter_words;
            try
            {

                IWebElement body = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > div.EtaWk"));
                bodyText = body.Text; //текст поста #react-root > section > main > div > div > article > div.eo2As > div.KlCQn.EtaWk > ul > li > div > div > div > span
            }
            catch (Exception) { filter_view_in_msg_box = "null"; return result = true;  }

            // Console.WriteLine(bodyText);

            string[] words = filters.Split(',');

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                result = Regex.IsMatch(bodyText, @"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (result == true)
                {
                    filter_view_in_msg_box = word;
                    return result;


                }

            }
            return result = false;
        }
        else { return result = true; }

    }






}
```

Т.е. получается разница только в CSS селекторах, а код идентичный.

Я сделал статический класс с константами

```
    public static class ConstantsApp
{
    public const String app_version = "1.2";
    public const String app_author = "Martinov A.";
    public const String url_tags = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"; //
    public const String url_geolocation = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/"; //
    public const String html_mark_open_first_post = "#react-root > section > main > article > div.EZdmt > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)"; // открыть пост Самая первая запись в теге
    public const String html_mark_panel_textbox = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > div.EtaWk"; // панель, где находится текст поста
    public const String html_mark_button_next = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.EfHg9 > div > div > a.HBoOv.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow"; // кнопка следующий пост (так же, можно использовать событие клавы)
    public const String html_mark_button_like = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button"; //кнопка лайка в открытом посте
    public const String html_mark_get_check_like = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > div.eo2As > section.ltpMr.Slqrh > span.fr66n > button > span"; // проверка стоит ли лайк
    public const String html_mark_button_subscribe = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button"; // //кнопка подпис. в открытом посте
    public const String html_mark_get_check_subscribe = "body > div._2dDPU.vCf6V > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button"; // проверка, подписаны ли
    public const String html_mark_name_attribut_grey_like = "glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7"; // имя атрибута когда лайк не стоит (серое сердечко)
    public const String html_mark_name_attribut_active_sucbscribe = "oW_lN _0mzm- sqdOP yWX7d    _8A5w5    "; // имя атрибута когда не подписаны

}
```

И хочу что бы у меня был только один метод, а не 4. Буду просто селекторы разные передавать в метод из статического класса с константами. 
Но при этом хотелось бы, что бы было два класса. Другими словами два класса и только один общий метод у них ну или что-то вроде этого))

P.S. за код не ругайте, я только учусь. =)

Comment: до конца не дочитаю, больно много, но если вам нужны 2 класса с общим методом, то вам нужно эти классы наследовать от общего класса или передавать в эти классы класс-помощник

Comment: Вот тоже об этом задумался, пожалуй, вполне красивое решение, благодарю. Попробую реализовать.

Comment: А по мне так наоборот, не надо все спихивать в один метод/класс, пусть будет классов по больше, и как правильно подмечено, использовать наследование. По сути для выполнения задачи вам понадобиться 4 класса: 1- класс с общими методами. 2-класс потомок первого с индивидуальными данными для лайканья, 3- класс потомок 1, с индивидуальной реализацией для подписок, и наконец 4- класс где происходит лайканье и подписка.

Comment: И при это код не будет дублироваться? Ну да, получается что так. Вот это я и хотел. А то, что лучше сделать больше классов: вполне резонно, будет легче читать код и понимать его когда всё разбито на множество классов, чем один класс с тысячу строками.

Comment: Вообще, все придумано до нас, вам не надо создавать парсер, а судя по коду вы парсите страницу, а необходимо использовать [API Twiter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/getting-started#get-started-app)

Comment: @Monomax [В чём преимущество наследования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962748/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) попробовал как вы предложили, но у меня трудности. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @АндрейИванов Оставил комментарии.

Answer (score 5):

я с АПИ твиттера не работал, потому покажу не боевой код, а скорее небольшое упражнение в ООП.

Первым делом нам нужен класс твита. Поля твита я взял из головы, но сделал его неизменяемым классом, так как, насколько я помню, твит поменять нельзя

```
public class TweetItem
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public string Author { get; }

    public TweetItem(string id, string text, string author)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Text = text;
        this.Author = author;
    }
}
```

Дальше, нам нужна возможность искать твиты. Так как поиск твитов может быть по разным критериям, я решил выделить интерфейс для поиска

```
public interface ITweetFilter
{
    IEnumerable<TweetItem> GetTweets();
}
```

Далее, какая-то реализация классов поиска

```
public class TweetFilterByTag : ITweetFilter
{
    private string _tag;
    public TweetFilterByTag(string tag)
    {
        _tag = tag;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TweetItem> GetTweets()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class TweetFilterByGeo : ITweetFilter
{
    private string _geo;
    public TweetFilterByGeo(string geo)
    {
        _geo = geo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TweetItem> GetTweets()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Поскольку поиск можно комбинировать, я решил также накатать композитный поиск.

```
public class TweetFilterComposite : ITweetFilter
{
    private ITweetFilter[] _filters;

    public TweetFilterComposite(params ITweetFilter[] filters)
    {
        _filters = filters;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TweetItem> GetTweets()
    {
        var foundTweets = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var filter in _filters)
            foreach (var tweet in filter.GetTweets())
                if (foundTweets.Add(tweet.Id))
                    yield return tweet;
    }
}
```

Далее, нам нужны классы, один для постановки лайков, второй - для подписки.

```
public class TweetLiker
{
    public void SetLike(TweetItem tweet)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TweetSubscriber
{
    public void Subscribe(TweetItem tweet)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Осталось соединить всё вместе в нашей логике

```
public class MyLogic
{   
    private TweetLiker _liker;
    private TweetSubscriber _subscriber;

    public MyLogic(TweetLiker liker, TweetSubscriber subscriber)
    {       
        _liker = liker;
        _subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    public void SetLike(ITweetFilter filter)
    {
        foreach(var tweet in filter.GetTweets()
        _liker.SetLike(tweet);
    }

    public void Subscribe(ITweetFilter filter)
    {
        foreach (var tweet in filter.GetTweets()
        _subscriber.Subscribe(tweet);
    }
}
```

Как всем этим пользоваться: создаем нужные фильтры, создаем логику и вперед.

```
var filterByTag = new TweetFilterByTag("MyTag");
var filterByGeo = new TweetFilterByGeo("MyCity");
var compositeFilter = new TweetFilterComposite(filterByTag, filterByGeo);

var myLogic = new MyLogic(new TweetLiker(), new TweetSubscriber());
myLogic.SetLike(compositeFilter);
myLogic.Subscribe(compositeFilter);
```

Comment: Но получается же, что это не решает проблему, т.к. в реализации интерфейса и классах TweetLiker и TweetSubscriber тоже будет дублироваться код. Хотя, скорее всего, я чего-то не понимаю, лучше приведу свой код сверху сейчас.

Comment: @АндрейИванов ну я ваш код не видел, потому только вам знать, что там дублируется :)